# Проблема с версиями зависимостей

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Есть веб-проект на ASP.NET MVC, в нем используется `Castle.Windsor (3.3.0)`, у которого есть зависимость `Castle.Core (>=3.3.0)`. При первоначальной установке из NuGet, подтянулись более новые бета-версии (`4.*..-beta2`), которые я проапдейтил (обе) вниз, до `3.3.0`.

При запуске приложения все равно получаю ошибку:

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Castle.Core" либо одну из их
>   зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует
>   ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)

...

> [FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Castle.Core,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc"
>   либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки
>   не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]

То есть якобы в манифесте требуется `4.0.0`, хотя ildasm говорит, что это не так.

В интернетах встречаются предложения настроить редирект версий в конфиге приложения, но это выглядит костылями, учитывая, что тестовый проект с этими зависимостями отлично собирается.

Comment: Поищите по конфигам проекта `4.4.0`, возможно как раз где то там и прописался редирект не на нужную вам версию.

Answer (score 6):

Проблемой оказался глобальный `Web.config` этого веб-проекта, в котором нашлись такие строки:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- .... -->
  <runtime>
    <!-- .... -->
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <!-- .... -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity culture="neutral" name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc"/>
        <bindingRedirect newVersion="4.0.0.0" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

После выпиливания проблемного узла `dependentAssembly` все благополучно заработало.